# Padding preceding blanks on a variable for Money or Disk Space lineup

Tags: csv, batch-file, variables, padding, sysinternals

OK, Basically I am echo'ing a line to a CSV comma delimited.

This is what is happening:

This is the output:

```
Computer1   Fri 08/04/2017  13:20   110 917 340 907
Computer2   Fri 08/04/2017  13:21   110 917 435 852
Computer3   Fri 08/04/2017  12:39   180 92  916 
Computer4   Fri 08/04/2017  12:35   232 353 720
```

I want:

```
Computer1   Fri 08/04/2017  13:20   110 917 340 907
Computer2   Fri 08/04/2017  13:21   110 917 435 852
Computer3   Fri 08/04/2017  12:39       180 92  916 
Computer4   Fri 08/04/2017  12:35       232 353 720
```

I want to lead with a comma for every 3rd right-justified character, so the values line up correctly.

I am getting size of folders to calculate current folder size, then again weekly to determine growth.

The part I am struggling with is this:

```
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims= " %%a in ('C:\du64.EXE -v -q -nobanner C:\Temp^|find "Size:"') do SET DISKSIZE=%%b
ECHO. "%DISKSIZE%" **
```

(This will give a value containing commas. ex 12,345,678,910)

```
ECHO. %COMPUTERNAME%,%DATE%,%TIME:~0,5%,%DISKSIZE%,%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%>> "C:\DUOutput.CSV"
```

Comment: The `92` on the `Computer3` line should be right justified; it just looks wrong. What we need is an explanation as to how your 'want' code bears any relationship to the last line of code, because I cannot see it at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
 ...set "DISKSIZE=                      %%b"
 echo %disksize:~-15%
```

No idea why you're getting `92` in your data, nor what `lead with a comma for every 3rd right-justified character` means.

see `set /?|more` from the prompt for documentation. I've no idea how many spaces I put before `%%b` - so long as there is at least a string of 15, it should be OK.